Conversion Value per Cost in Google Ads Always 0 Despite ROAS and Proper Firebase Implementation
I’ve been running a Google Ads campaign with conversion value tracking set up via Firebase for my Android games. Recently, without making any updates to the build or Firebase setup, the Conversion Value per Cost (CVPC) in Google Ads always shows 0, even though I’m seeing some Return on Ad Spend (ROAS) in my reports.
Details:

Setup:

Firebase is integrated with Google Ads using automatic event tracking.

Conversion events are correctly defined in Firebase, with associated revenue values.



Testing:

I have verified the following:

Firebase events, including revenue-related custom events, are logged correctly in the Firebase DebugView.

Conversion values are calculated accurately in Firebase reports.

The conversion event used for Google Ads is marked as a conversion in Firebase.





Issue:

Despite the correct implementation and visible ROAS in the Google Ads dashboard, the Conversion Value per Cost remains 0 across all campaigns in Google Ads.

This issue began recently without any changes to the build or campaign settings.




enter image description here
enter image description here

Steps Taken So Far:

Double-checked Firebase setup and conversion event values.

Verified that the Google Ads conversion event in Firebase is properly configured with a monetary value.

Confirmed the Google Ads account linking with Firebase.

Contacted Google Ads support, but they have not been able to identify the root cause.





Questions:

Has anyone experienced a similar issue where CVPC in Google Ads shows 0 despite working Firebase implementation?

Could this be an issue with how Google Ads processes conversion values, even though Firebase is logging events correctly?

Are there additional checks or debugging steps I can take to resolve this issue?


Let me know if any details are missing or need clarification. I would really appreciate insights or guidance from the community!
